# Получить bean с его внутренним состоянием из spring (bean, который уже поднят и находится в работе)

Tags: java, spring

Здравствуйте. Если кратко, то есть два класса. Оба компоненты Spring. Первый класс используется внутри второго и инициализируется через @Inject. Тут все нормально работает. Вопрос такой: что прописать в spring-context.xml, чтобы получить первый класс с его внутренним состоянием (со всеми полями)? Повторюсь, первый класс был инжекнут и я так понимаю его как-то можно вытянуть из spring'a. Пока у меня есть вот такой джавакод:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("service-context.xml");
AdministratorCaching administratorCaching = (AdministratorCaching) context.getBean("AdministratorCaching");
```

А в spring-context.xml имеется такая строка для связавания. Но она я так понимаю не верна, так как поднимает бин из файловой системы (создает новый бин):

```
<bean id="AdministratorCaching" class="com.yauhenikuntsevich.training.onlinestore.services.caching.AdministratorCaching"></bean>
```

Comment: Пару раз прочитал и ничего не понял. Что не работает и какую проблему вы решаете? Вместо первый и второй класс лучше укажите их названия. Вижу только `AdministratorCaching` -- это первый или второй? Кто в кого инжектится?

Comment: Если вы несколько раз используете `@Inject`, то получите один и тот же объект со всем его внутренним состоянием.

Comment: Проблема такая. Есть класс в сервис слое вебприложения, AdministratorServiceImpl. В этом классе есть класс AdministratorCaching, в котором реализовано кеширование данных, которые проходят из базы наверх через методы класса AdministratorServiceImpl. В классе AdministratorCaching есть Map, которая и является кэшем, в нее сохраняются данные. И вот в свою очередь при остановке приложения мне нужно сериализовать AdministratorCaching в файл, чтобы восстановить его при запуске приложения. Поэтому мне нужно как-то достать из Spring'a класс  AdministratorCaching в его актуальном состоянии.

Comment: Nick Savenia, я это и хочу сделать, но не знаю как. За этим и обратился сюда)

Comment: Если вы не указываете scope бину - то по-умолчанию он синглтон. А значит будет один и тот же, где бы вы его не подинимали. С чего вы решили, что каждый раз создается новый бин? Может где-то дальше по коду вы используете не его же, а создаете новый на основании поднятого из контекста? Или ещё что-то....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно знать суть понятия "Bean Scopes", их существует на текущий момент пять: `singleton`, `prototype`, `request`, `session`, `global-session`.

Задаются они через XML атрибут при определении бина или как параметр аннотации, в зависимости от того какой из способов вы используете - основанный на XML или java-base, для описания spring контекста. По умолчанию, т.е. если вы не задает этот параметр, все бины имеют singleton scope.

Bean Scopes - это стратегия создания экземпляров бина, говоря языком Java - стратегия создания объектов класса, которым является ваш бин.
В случае `singleton`, на все приложение создается только один объект(экземпляр класса). И каждый другой бин в который вы внедряете ваш, по средствам `@Inject`/`@Autowire` будет попросту получать ссылку на один единственный экземпляр, который по сути `singleton`.